# Array iteration with static final limits

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array:

```
final int[] exampleArray = new int[ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

And I can iterate that array several ways, for example:

Way 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < exampleArray.length; i++) {
    // code where I use 'i' index
}
```

Way 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    // code where I use 'i' index
}
```

Which way is better? Are there any other better ways to do it?

Comment: 1) Way 1 will always work (until `exampleArray == null`) 2) Way 1 explicitly shows your intentions 3) use `for ( final int a : exampleArray )` if you don't need `i`

Comment: Way 1 allows consistency with non-final arrays as well (ie. parameters where you don't know the size ahead of time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need `i` for anything else than extracting the element, then the enhanced for loop looks a bit nicer:

```
for(int element : exampleArray) {
//code that uses element
}
```

If you are using i for both accessing the array, and something else, then I would argue Way 1 is best:

```
for (int i = 0; i < exampleArray.length; i++) {
    // code where I use 'i' index
}
```

The reason is that the next time someone looks at a code, the person will immediately see that you are iterating to the length of the array. If you go for way 2 (using a constant), the reader might wonder if that constant really is the length of your array.

Comment: @shreyanshjogi: Oh? hows that?

Comment: @shreyanshjogi - The enhanced `for` loop was introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: @Ted Hopp:- sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Tackling both performance, and code readability, way 2 is better.

Rated by performance, by using `exampleArray.length` you are calling upon a "*member*" variable which requires additional java bytecode to request when compared to calling a "*local*" variable.  But, the difference in performance is extremely minuscule and you would never notice it unless you were making an extreme amount of calculations.

Rated by readability, ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE lays out your intent for whomever is reading, which is more important than it may seem.  Yet, too many programmers lay out nonsensical or ambiguous variable names, and it makes reading their code lacking in naturalness.  Naming variables and functions in a way that makes sense to our minds in an organic way makes the code much simpler to deal with for yourself in the future, and anyone else, making it a good practice.

Comment: how is way 2 more readable? If I would have seen ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE in the for loop I would have to check both if ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE really is final and if ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE is used where exampleArray is created. My guess is also that you will not have any real performance gain by doing way 1.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference in the two approaches, I see is as below:

In Way 1: you use the constant exampleArray.length in the loop condition
In Way 2: you use the constant ID_DATA_ARRAY_SIZE in the loop condition

Obviously way 2 is superior in terms of performance.

This is because you are accessing a constant rather than access member variable of exampleArray object. This advantage is realized in every iteration of the for loop where the value of length member is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

see it is all about personal taste which way you wanna do but whenever you are working with array better to check null for the array and then do your stuff